# Closing Contours 'Up' and 'Down' in a Contour Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am considering an integral which can be evaluated using techniques from complex variables.  The first step is to simplify the integral.

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}dk\:\frac{e^{ikr}-e^{-ikr}}{k} = \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \Bigg[ \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}dk\:\frac{e^{ikr}-e^{-ikr}}{k+i\delta} \Bigg]$$

Obviously if $\delta >0$, then there is a pole at $-i \delta$.  However, the author then says that for the $e^{ikr}$ part, we close the contour up in the contour integral to get exponential decay for large $k$: the contour then misses the pole to get a zero result.  For the $e^{-ikr}$ part we have to close the contour down such that there is a loop around the pole which is evaluated using the residue theorem to get a final non-zero result.

It might just be the 'idiomatic' writing style of the author but I am just not sure what is meant when the author talks about closing up and closing down in this context: could someone clarify for me and maybe draw the contour which is being described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the integral in two:
$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}dk\:\frac{e^{ikr}-e^{-ikr}}{k+i\delta}
= \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}dk\:\frac{e^{ikr}}{k+i\delta}
- \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}dk\:\frac{e^{-ikr}}{k+i\delta}
$$

For the first integral we take the following contour:

[image]

For the second integral we instead let the semicircle be in the negative imaginary halfplane:

[image]